# Instant App publish error

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

When i publish preview version, play store tip:
You must use at least one APK that maps to the "**example.com**" site via the network "**intent-filter**".
It no problem on develop version.

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        <meta-data
                android:name="default-url"
                android:value="https://example.com/"/>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            <data
                    android:host="example.com"
                    android:pathPattern="/"
                    android:scheme="https"/>
            <data android:scheme="http"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

because it is the test phase, so the online version of the installation App has not added default url. add `default-url` to installation App `manifest.xml` it will be ok.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18230334)

Comment: @alesc answer seems self answer.